# how to do a filter search for the heading in listview

Tags: android, search, filter

i got a listview that consists of thingsToDo[] time[] deadline[] and i want to search by the thingsToDo[].

I tried doing filter search but it will filter the whole listview, not what i really want.

Helps will be greatly appreaciate

Answer (score 0):

you Override toString of object that is in your collection and set:

```
 listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

When set to true, the list will filter results as the user types. The List's adapter must support the Filterable interface for this to work.
Must be a boolean value, either "true" or "false".
This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.
This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol textFilterEnabled.

and also refer :: [**this**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html)

Comment: thank but it will filter everything in the listview right ? including date[] and time []